# Is APT slated for deprecated with SNAP on the horizon?

Tags: apt, package-management, snap, ubuntu-core

With the emergence of Ubuntu Snap, the idea of Linux packages that are cross-platform and easily updateable are finally a reality. with that being said, is Ubuntu planning on making all of its official packages snap apps or just apps made by independent developers? If they do plan on making all of their applications snap apps, whats the timeline?

Comment: No, and I don't think most of the apps would be usable on a snaps-only system.

Comment: Is there any reason why you think that? if configured right, they could make a file browser that works through snap, and then it might be good to go.

Comment: I certainly hope not.

Comment: Simply due to the design of snaps, and how traditional apps/libraries/services work. It is by no means easy to make an entire end-user target system be built solely with snaps. Unity 8 never got fully working with snaps only, and it was at least designed around a lot of the same principles. I don't want to think about what it would take to get GNOME/KDE/etc... properly confined as such.

Answer (score 0):

On platforms using [Ubuntu Core](https://www.ubuntu.com/core) which is intended for IoT devices apt packages may (or have already) go away.

But on the server and the desktop they will not. The core system will likely keep using apt packages for a long time. But user application may move to snaps depending on their use case and dependency problems they could face.